# Caching external images with Rails fragment caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am using Rails' fragment caching to cache these individual "widgets" which were turning out to be pretty hefty calls

```
<%= render partial: 'championships/championship', collection: @championships, cached: true %>
```

It is all working fine and as expected. However another reason for doing this is that each widget makes a call for an image which is externally hosted on [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com) and I wanted to reduce the number of calls we were making there. However, when I load the page and look at Network requests, I am still seeing requests to Uploadcare for each of these images.

[image]

Am I mis-reading this? Are these possibly just being recalled from cache or are they actually making the external request? Is there any way to include these external images in the fragment caching?

https://www.redlinemotorsport.co.uk

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how your `championship` partial looks like, but I would expect, that there is something like this for images:

```
<img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" alt="alt">
```

or `image_tag` if it is in the rails helper.

In this case, only this tag is cached, not image itself. Image is then downloaded by the browser during HTML processing and rendering.

Fragment caching is probably not the right way for image caching. Don't get me wrong, you can cache images with fragment caching, but you would have to embed the image directly into the view, not just images URL address. It looks something like this:

```
<img src=”data:<MIMETYPE>;base64,<BASE64_ENCODED_IMAGE>”>
```

More info about it can be found eg here: https://www.bigfastblog.com/embed-base64-encoded-images-inline-in-html. Image would be embedded directly into the view and cached with the HTML fragment. But it is not usable for images from the external websites and you probably shouldn't do it anyway.

It is true that browser will do a lot of requests to the external sites (CDN) but on the other hand it will usually use HTTP Caching, it only downloads new or changed images. Rest of the images are only checked whether they have been changed, if they haven't, they won't be downloaded again, they will be loaded from the browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You're getting those from browser memory (cache).
At Uploadcare we're working hard on improving web performance, so unless you're doing anything weird, browsers will cache your images for good :)